# Faster estimation of logarithm operation

Tags: python, performance, numpy, logarithm

I have a fairly simple function involving a logarithm of base 10 (`f1` shown below). I need it to run as fast as possible since it is called millions of times as part of a larger code.

I tried with a [Taylor approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20log(1%2B10%5Ex)&rawformassumption=%7B%22FunClash%22,%20%22log%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Log10%22%7D) (`f2` below) but even with a large expansion the accuracy is very poor and, *even worse*,  it ends up taking a lot more time.

Have I reached the limit of performance attainable with `numpy`?

```
import time
import numpy as np

def f1(m1, m2):
    return m1 - 2.5 * np.log10(1. + 10 ** (-.4 * (m2 - m1)))


def f2(m1, m2):
    """
    Taylor expansion of 'f1'.
    """
    x = -.4 * (m2 - m1)
    return m1 - 2.5 * (
        0.30102999 + .5 * x + 0.2878231366 * x ** 2 -
        0.0635837 * x ** 4 + 0.0224742887 * x ** 6 -
        0.00904311879 * x ** 8 + 0.00388579 * x ** 10)


# The data I actually use has more or less this range.
N = 1000
m1 = np.random.uniform(5., 30., N)
m2 = np.random.uniform(.7 * m1, m1)

# Test both functions
M = 5000
s = time.clock()
for _ in range(M):
    mc1 = f1(m1, m2)
t1 = time.clock() - s
s = time.clock()
for _ in range(M):
    mc2 = f2(m1, m2)
t2 = time.clock() - s

print(t1, t2, np.allclose(mc1, mc2, 0.01))
```

Comment: Is `numpy.log10` really too slow for you?

Comment: At the moment it is clearly the fastest option, but this function is currently the bottleneck of my code (~30% of the total run time) and a better performance would certainly help.

Comment: By using numba I managed to reduce in about 20% the execution time.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Show some benchmarks as i find that hard to believe. Either log is complete hardware or numpy's log is old optimized asm/c/fortran where numba should do nothing.

Comment: Ok, ran it again and only found 20% (dunno why it was lower before). ´101 µs ± 3.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)´ for the undecorated while ´81.3 µs ± 2.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)´ for the @jit decorated version.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel So you are talking about f2 i suppose?

Comment: @BlackBear that hadn't occurred to me, I'll try it now.

Comment: @sascha no, f1.

Comment: BlackBear deleted his/her comment, I tried and changing from base 10 to base 2 results in a code faster by ~10%.

Comment: There are also [bit twiddling approaches](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10), which can be [implemented in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation). You could also try using a log base 2 calculation, and convert it to a log base 10 with a single multiplication/division operation.

Comment: @charlesreid1 not sure if that's necessary, I can change log bases with a simple division.

Comment: I mention the change of base because log base 2 is faster than log base 10, for the same reason that bit manipulation is fast - it takes advantage of the inherent bit-based machine representation. To make your computations scream you have to get closer to the bits and the bare metal.

Comment: Yes, as I stated above a change of base to log2 makes the `f1` function ~10% faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code-snippet, **i'm not sure if you should optimize the log, but more the whole vector-expression itself**.

You can try [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) (Fast numerical array expression evaluator for Python, NumPy,...), which might do a lot for you.

The idea to try this came from Ignacio's comment which made me think where his speedup is coming from (i'm sure, it's not coming from the log calculation itself).

In my simple modification of your code:

```
import numexpr as ne
def f1(m1, m2):
   return ne.evaluate("m1 - 2.5 * log10( 1.0 + 10 ** (-0.4 * (m2-m1)))")
```

it seems the above is **5 - 6x times as fast as (an unoptimized) f2 (approximation)**, while still giving the original accuracy.

It's also **nearly twice as fast** as the original numpy-approach **f1**.

These numbers might change depending on numexpr's setup as Intels MKL for example could be used too. As i'm too lazy to check my anaconda-based setup, i offer this just as a tech-demo, which everyone can try out too.

While i used numexpr a few times in the past for simple stuff, i might add, that it's also used within [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#recommended-dependencies), just to mention a real-world project depending on it's correct workings.

Disclaimer: i used your benchmark as template (and hope caching and co does not play a role).

Comment: I'm trying this approach but I find that it is *less* than 2X faster than the original unoptimized approach `f1`, and **slower** than the optimized approach `f2` with pjs' modification. I'm running Python 2.7.13, could that be the reason for the much better performance you find?

Comment: That's ~ what i achieve too, if we are talking about f1. And i never used numexpr on f2. So just take this as demo, do your own tests and check numexpr setup-possibilities.

Comment: I'm not sure to which function you are referring as the "original unoptimized" versus the "original numpy-approach".. This solution however is perfectly accurate.

Comment: I said: original unoptimized **approximation**. That should have been clear. But yeah, we should be more careful. Your 3x faster comment under pjs' answer could also interpreted differently.

Answer (score 3):

Replace all of those exponentiations in `f2` with multiplication:

```
def f2(m1, m2):
    """
    Taylor expansion of 'f1'.
    """
    x = -0.4 * (m2 - m1)
    x2 = x * x
    x4 = x2 * x2
    x6 = x4 * x2
    return m1 - 2.5 * (
        0.30102999 + .5 * x + 0.2878231366 * x2 -
        0.0635837 * x4 + 0.0224742887 * x6 -
        0.00904311879 * x4 * x4 + 0.00388579 * x4 * x6)
```

Comment: @Gabriel You're welcome.  Now the question is whether it's accurate enough for you.

Comment: pjs, it is not actually. I'll try adding a few more terms to the expansion and see if the increase in performance holds.

Comment: Even adding several more terms to this code, the accuracy is not enough and the ~3X improvement drops rapidly. This answer has the advantage of not needing any extra packages though.